# Reading std::string, remove all special characters from a std::string

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11, split

I am very new to this forum and c++. So pardon me for my doubts/ questions. I am trying to read a `std::string`. I know I can access the elements using `at` or `[int]` operator. I've 2 questions:

1) remove or erase all special characters from string (includes spaces)

2) read only first 4 characters or letters from this string

For 1), I am checking on `std::erase` and `std::remove_if`but I need to eliminate all I mean special characters and spaces too. This means I need to include all the conditions that `isspace()`/ `isalpha()` and so on. Is there no single method to remove all at once?

For 2), I can access the string like an array, I mean string[0], string[1], string[2], string[3]. But I can't add this into single string?

Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: Which characters are "special characters"?

Comment: Yes I mean all in the second row of our keyboards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the first four characters:

```
std::string first4=str.substr(0, 4);
```

To remove anything that isspace and isalpha predicates (although I think I misunderstood, here, do you mean isspace and is not isalpha??):

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
    [](char c) { return std::isspace(c) || std::isalpha(c); } ),
    str.end());
```

You can append to the string using `op+=`. For example:

```
str+="hello";
str+='c';
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all special characters, why not make a method like so:

```
bool isLegal(char c)
{
  char legal[] = {'a', 'A', 'b','B' /*..and so on*/};
  int len = sizeof(legal)/sizeof(char);

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if (c == legal[i])
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

and then just iterate trough the string and remove the characters not legal?

Answer (score 0):

For 1: std::remove_if will remove all elements for which the given predicate returns true. You provide the predicate function object, and it can be whatever you want it to be so long as it takes an element from your container (char) and returns a bool.

So you can write a function such as:

```
bool IsNotLegal(const char & stringElement);
```

or you can write it as a lambda function, and then you can pass it to std::remove_if to remove everything from the string that satisfies your conditions in 1 pass.

```
std::string myString{"This is my string."};
std::remove_if(std::begin(myString), std::end(myString),[](const char & element)
{
    return std::isspace(element) && //any other conditions such as your own IsSpecial();
});
// now myString has become "Thisismystring."
```

Answer (score 0):

Old stuff, but here is my solution.

```
  void ClearSpecialCharacters(std::string &strText, const std::string& strAllowed)
{
    const std::string cAllowed = strAllowed; //"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,.-";
    
    
    auto new_end = std::remove_if(strText.begin(), strText.end(),
                                  [cAllowed](std::string::value_type c)
                                  { return cAllowed.find(c) == std::string::npos; });
    
    
    
    strText.erase(new_end, strText.end());
}
```