# Remove special character and string after it inside char array

Tags: c++, regex, string, char

I have an email with type char array:

```
char email[80] = "pewdiepie@harvard.edu.au"
```

How can I remove the `@` and string after it and get `pewdiepie` as the final result?

Comment: check this , maybe it work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971804/reading-stdstring-remove-all-special-characters-from-a-stdstring

Answer (score 4):

For example the following way

```
if ( char *p = std::strchr( email, '@' ) ) *p = '\0';
```

In C you have to declare variable `p` before the if statement. For example

```
char *p;
if ( ( p = strchr( email, '@' ) ) != NULL ) *p = '\0';
```

If instead of the character array to use an object of type `std::string` as for example

```
std::string email( "pewdiepie@harvard.edu.au" );
```

then you can write

```
auto pos = email.find( '@' );
if ( pos != std::string::npos ) email.erase(pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
#include <string>

std::string email("pewdiepie@harvard.edu.au");
email.erase(email.find('@'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on keeping it has a char[], rather than a string

```
char email[80] = "pewdiepie@harvard.edu.au";
char name[80]; // to hold the new string

name[std::find(email, email + 80, '@') - email] = '\0'; // put '\0' in correct place
strncpy(name, email, std::find(email, email + 80, '@') - email); // copy the string
```

If you want to alter the original char[],

```
*(std::find(email, email + 80, '@')) = '\0';
```